# usb-serial module not found in ubuntu 21.10 aarch64

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

Recently updated the OS on my raspberry pi from Hirsute to Impish, but now nothing is showing up in `ls -al /dev/serial/by-id` even though the device shows up in `lsusb`.

Running `lsmod | grep serial` turns up nothing, and when I run `sudo modprobe usb-serial` I get `modprobe: FATAL: Module usb-serial not found in directory /lib/modules/5.13.0-1008-raspi`

Not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Is there no usb serial module for this kernel?

Comment: Finding similar here, only with Hirsute.  USB to RS-232 adapters which normally work, just don't show up consistently when plugged in.  I added the "dialout" and "plugdev" groups to my login id and rebooted.  Still not working properly.

In my case it will occasionally load the "ftdi-sio" module in support of "usbserial" but it's not consistent and eventually it fails.